# How can I trace an object that move along equation?

Tags: modeling, animation

How can I trace an object like this gif?
Actually I made an animation with mathematics that an object move along a math equation. What I want is to draw a path that the object has taken like below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using geometry nodes. Just generate a mesh line with length of current frame and move its points according to the equation:

[image]

Comment: @FarhadDorri Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).