# To and fro, or back and forth using sine

Tags: mathematics

I want to make a to and fro motion on x using a sinusoidal equation. I saw it on a tutorial recently but i can't find it again.

Comment: Something like the ping pong node
https://youtu.be/9y0HHYD7Lxo

Comment: using python? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270888/draw-a-sine-wave-from-a-revolving-unit-circle-in-blender

Answer (score 3):

Add a location keyframe for your object anywhere by hitting **I** in object mode and choosing *Location*.

In the Graph Editor select the keyframe for the X value, then go to the properties panel (hit **N** if you don't see it).

In the *Modifiers* tab choose *Add Modifier > Built-In Function*

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Click the object's X Location to edit it, and type in `#sin(frame/20)`.

This will create a driver with a scripted expression `sin(frame/20)` which sets the X location to the SIN of the current frame value divided by 20. Making the cube move on X between -1 and 1 every ~63 frames.

Comment: Hello, could you please tell a bit more?

Comment: A simple back and forth. Or up-down continuous motion.